# How do I use an authenticated proxy with special char in password with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My Environment is Windows 7 (Try not to laugh) and I am using the binary download of JMeter 4.

I am trying the following command to start it...

```
 jmeter -H my.proxy -P 1234 -u myName -a myPassword
```

My password has the `#` character in it.

When I try to run my Test I get...

> Response message: Proxy Authentication Required

I think it might be related to my special char given a couple other SOs.

So how would I change this command so I can send valid requests?

Comment: did you try to put it in quotes? e.g. `jmeter -H my.proxy -P 1234 -u myName -a "myPassword"`

Comment: I am not sure this will help, I eventually found the advanced settings and it hadn't recognized params (or at least didn't autofill anything). I will still double check your suggestion soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My password had "&" character in it. For me also, i tried url encoding i.e. `%26` and it did not work. But, it worked when i tried html encoding i.e. replaced `&` with `&amp;` or `&#0026;`.

For all html encoded characters, refer this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) page. For `#` symbol, you can use `&#0023;`